# Error message with MANOVA

Tags: r, manova

I am having trouble with a MANOVA. I have an experiment with 6 response variable (say, A, B, C, D, E and F), and 3 explanatory variables (say R1, R2 and R3). I used `cbind()` (which I will call "y") to link my 6 response variables together, and then used this in my model as follows:

```
model <- manova(y ~ R1*R2*R3)
```

This is working without problem, I can obtain the results from my MANOVA, everything is fine. However, as my response variables are habitats of different sizes, it has been pointed out to me that I should correct my data to account for these differences in size. Once I do this, however, my MANOVA sends an error message which I do not understand :

```
Error in summary.manova(model) : residuals have rank 5 < 6
```

It seems that this message usually appears when a dataset has more columns than rows, which is not my case (I have about 9 columns and about 132 rows). Also, it is confusing me as my dataset after correction is very similar to the one before the correction (same amount of columns, same amount of rows, and in both cases all the values for my response variables are between 0 and 1).

Any idea why I get this error message with the second model and not the first one?

Comment: Hi @Anne, what software are you using? My guess is **R**, but you should be specific. Also, including a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) would be helpful.

Comment: I had the same error, and it turned out that I had entered the same predictor twice. More generally, make sure that none of your predictors are perfectly correlated after your transformation.

Comment: if anyone is looking for answers on this page, stack overflow has a good couple of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412865/error-in-summary-manova-residuals-have-rank-order-deficiency